# ASP .NET system design advice.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, service

I'm working on a system (.NET website) that uses class libraries to manipulate data located on a MS SQL server. Lately, I've been wondering about ditching those classes and doing the data manipulation using WCF. That way I could consume the services in Android, Java, etc...

Well, some classes return a large amount of data, say a 125x10000 datatable... and I'm worried that WCF will not be able to handle that... or maybe that the system's performance will suffer too much.

What do you guys think?
Is WCF ok to to use for retrieving/updating large amounts of data on a multi-user system?
If not, what are some other options?

Comment: That's probably too much.  Do you always need an entire data dump?  Can you do more of the work in queries on the server and return smaller data sets?  Can you (at least) page the results so that they are in groups of a few hundred/thousand?

Comment: Yes. Need entire data dump... and yes, can do paging... but still too much, right?

Comment: Can you add methods to the WFC to reduce the date dump? like:
 getItemByID(int id);
 getItemByName(string name);
 getItemLike(string name)

Comment: How would you guys design, what kind of technology, would you guys use to build a multi-user system that often is used to retrieve/update large amounts of data?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that each of the apps can't go to the SQL database directly to get the full data dump?

Comment: @hbrock: Yes, I currently use data filters, where engineers can make selections and return smaller amounts of data, but most of the time they need to see large data sets.

Comment: @Servi: Well, I use a combination of user input with already stored SQL data to calculate and return the final data set. I could use stored procedures and pass the user parameters to them, but all the calculation would tie the SQL server up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like what you're suggesting is moving the database load to the application side - pulling entire data tables to the application in order to run your would-be DB operation.That's kind of what the SQL server is designed for.

By doing so, you're putting all of the load onto your application server and underutilizing the DB area of concern. Write some code to handle locking and then let the database do it's job. You'll end up writing more procs, but that's normal, and better in the long run as you can edit them on the back end without having to recompile app code. IMO do all of your database operations in your stored procedure and return the smaller result sets through WCF.

I mean... are you really planning on piping that much info over a WCF service onto cellphone?!

Comment: hahah the company had better pay for a true unlimited data plan if they want me to use that app... :D